# c++ 20 concepts alternative in c#

Tags: c#, templates, generics, operators

In c++ 20 we can use `concepts` which works like the `where` keyword in c# but I'm wondering how can i check `T` has some operator overloaded on it.

**c++ Example:-**

```
template <class T>
concept SupportPlusEqual = requires (T t) { t += t };

template <class T>
requires SupportPlusEqual <T>
void Add (T& lhs, T& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
}
```

In this code `T` must have `+=` operator defined.

> Is there any way to do the same in `c#`?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators you can check the **Non overloadable operators** part

Comment: Sadly, no, not directly. In general this would be called [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) (someone correct me if I'm wrong) and we don't have the ability to directly do it code. It is used in some places in the language itself though, for example to use something in a `foreach` expression it doesn't *have* to implement `IEnumerable` it can simply expose a `IEnumerator GetEnumerator` method since `foreach` is "only" syntactic sugar. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cBCvKH) is a demonstration if you're interested

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the closest equivalent is if you use .NET 7, interfaces can now specify operators with the new [static abstract and virtual members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface#static-abstract-and-virtual-members) feature. For example:

```
public interface IHasAdd<T> where T : IHasAdd<T>
{
    static abstract T operator +(T a, T b);
}
```

To use it, make a type like this:

```
public class Foo : IHasAdd<Foo>
{
    public Foo(int someValue)
    {
        SomeValue = someValue;
    }
    
    public int SomeValue { get; init; }
    
    public static Foo operator +(Foo a, Foo b)
    {
        return new Foo(a.SomeValue + b.SomeValue);
    }
}
```

An example method that can use the interface:

```
public T AddTogether<T>(T first, T second)
    where T : IHasAdd<T>
{
    return first + second;
}
```

Which means you can now do this:

```
var result = AddTogether(new Foo(1), new Foo(2));
//result.SomeValue == 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only restrict generic types to interfaces, there is no way to require a specific operator to be implemented.

From .Net 7 there is the [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math) feature that accomplishes something similar. This includes a bunch of interfaces, like [IAdditionOperators<TSelf,TOther,TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.iadditionoperators-3?view=net-7.0), that can be used as a generic type restriction, and should also have associated operators defined to perform the corresponding operator.

Note that c++ templates and c# generic while superficially similar are implemented quite differently. While c++ resolves everything in compile time, c# includes the generic types in the CIL code, and is only converted to machine code when jitted.

Comment: Minor nitpick, but generic math isn't a C# 7 feature, it's .NET 7 feature, C# 7 is quite a bit older than .NET 7 and is supported by .NET Framework which sadly doesn't have the generic math interfaces

Comment: @MindSwipe, Oups, your right.